# Padding of div not working when div next to it is floating?

Tags: html, css

So I have 2 divs. One is a side bar on the page that's floating to the left. Then I have a main body div to its right. Before i changed the side bar to floating, I could set the margin and padding for the main div with no problems. However, if the sidebar is set to float,then the styling on the main div stops taking effect. Here's the css:

```
  #columns {
  background: #141;


  #main {
    margin-left: 17em;
    padding: 1em;
    padding-left: 3em;
    background: blue;
  }

  #side {
    float: left;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    width: 13em;
    background: #141;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-right: 2em;


    ul {
      padding: 0;
      li {
        list-style: none;
        a {
          color: #bfb;
          font-size: small;
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm guessing this is some property of float that I'm not aware of. Any ideas?

Comment: It has been a long time since I use HTML and CSS but I remember that when I made something similar I had to put the: 'float: left' to both elements. Try to put 'float: left' to the #main div.

Comment: Yep,I just did that and it works. I'm still curious why it behaves that way though.

Comment: It could behave like that for a variety of reason. One thing that really helps is a demonstration of your current html & css using a tool like jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @RomarioRamirez You should convert your comment to answer as it worked for me, and I would upvote it

Answer (score 1):

## Why does this happen?

Let's have a look at [a simple explanation of `float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float#How_floats_are_positioned):

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from
>   the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its
>   container, where **text and inline elements** will wrap around it. A
>   floating element is one where the computed value of float is not none.

Let's see this in action with the main div set to inline:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#main {
  background: blue;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
#side {
  float: left;
  width: 13em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="side">

</div>

<div id="main">

</div>
```

#### Result

The inline div is wrapped around it, brilliant.

Now let's make that div back to `display: block`, the default:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#main {
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#side {
  float: left;
  width: 13em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="side">

</div>

<div id="main">

</div>
```

#### Result

The block div is *underneath* the floated div! Why!? Let's look at that explanation again:

> The float CSS property specifies that an element **should be taken from
>   the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its
>   container**, where text and inline elements will wrap around it. A
>   floating element is one where the computed value of float is not none.

#### Interpretation

The floated div is taken out of the normal document flow and the block div ignores it.

### How can I prevent this behaviour and still use floats?

Simple, take the block div out of the normal flow as well; apply `float: left`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#main {
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
#side {
  float: left;
  width: 13em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="side">

</div>

<div id="main">

</div>
```